# Compartir proyectos entre soluciones de Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy armando la arquitectura de un proyecto bastante grande y básicamente es la siguiente:

**Solución pricipal**: cuenta con 10 proyectos (8 libreria de clases, WebAPI y MVC)

**Solución N** (proyecto mvc y web api) (La cantidad de estas soluciones va a depender de la cantidad de clientes que adquieran el servicio)

Toda la logica, incluida la de las soluciones N se encuentra en la solucion principal, lo cual la idea es que las soluciones N hagan referencia a las DLL de la solucion principal. ¿Es correcto esto?

El problema que le encuentro a esto es que si un cliente necesita un requerimiento especifico, ¿qué debería hacer? ¿Agregar ese requerimiento a la solución principal o crear un proyecto aparte (una dll) dentro de la solución N?

Saludos

Comment: Puedes detallar un poco más de que tratan tus soluciones? No es fácil dar un consejo sobre proyectos y soluciones hipotéticas  ya que sin contexto son simplemente nodos en un grafo.

Comment: Hola! ¿Esto está versionado? ¿TFS, git? te pregunto porque me suena mas a un `branch` de la rama principal que una cuestión de referencias a dll's.

Comment: ¿Por que el proyecto se planteo de esa manera? ¿No es un requerimiento especifico un desvió del contexto de la solución? Por ende, no seria mas parte del conjunto solución si existe tal requerimiento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta es una de las grandes preguntas de como "organizar" nuestros "artefactos" ... que a es el elixir de los arquitectos ;)
Hay muchas aproximaciones y para cada una que se deben evaluar características propias del proyecto como del "entorno" (equipo de proyecto, grado de volatilidad de requerimientos, que tan desacoplado son los componentes o módulos, etc) 
Como te comentan @jasilva a medida que avanzas en el proyecto puedes ir "explorando estas arquitecturas" para que no sea un impedimento al comienzo o peor que se atrase todo por tener una arquitectura "sobre dimensionada" para los primeros pasos de bebes de un proyecto.. como te dirán hay que caminar! (y así es) pero puedes ir tomando desde el principio algunas "mejoras practicas" que eso es al fin y al cabo.

Bueno.. todos comenzamos con proyectos "solos para un cliente"! y fueron creciendo para convertirse algunos en Paquetes de Software para customizarlo por cliente o incluso como SaaS (Multi-Tenant). Donde a cada paso tienes que "refactorizar lo creado y armado" para que pueda soportar los nuevos requerimientos de personalización y solicitud de varios clientes al mismo modulo por ejemplo

Comenzamos... si bien hace un par de años la unica forma de compartir era "referenciando" hoy en dia tienes mejoras practicas **con los paquetes de componentes** (NuGet del dia que lo utilizas) y por **ejemplo con DI (Inyección de dependencia)** puedes realizar lo mismo sin tanto **acoplamiento**, que al fin y al cabo es lo que queremos lograr en cada "modulo"

Recomendaciones

- Comienza como puedas.. con los proyectos "referenciados en la misma solucion". (como te comentaron se puede poner lento, inmanejable por la cantidad de archivos y por el proceso de compilación)
- Si ya lo has venido trabando asi... A medida que crezca. Conviértelos en componentes que puedas desacoplar e instalar en cada "personalización de cliente" como paquetes. INcluso aqui la ventaja es que para cad cliente tienes la "version" que utilizas y asi puedes ir agregando a cada cliente (proyecto separado) el paquete de la version. INCLUSO tema delacionado a estilos y javascript (que tambien puedes version en paquetes)
- Obviamente aqui tendrias que tener un servidor de paquetes interno ([Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds))
- Cuando los modulos vayan creciendo un paso mas es utilizar un mecanismo de publicacion, integracion, instalacion mas adaptable (composeable) para eso puedes darle una mirada a [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd460648.aspx)... para tener componentes de tu core "quesea plugins" Que lo puedes instalar simplemente copiando el assemblie correspondiente
- Si bien esto ultimo lo puedes hacer con Reflection (es mucho mas amigable con MEF)

Entonces puedes tener con la parte de "modulos" lo que comente mas arriba, con respecto a CORE

1. OPCION 1: Tener un solo core y realizar todo... web, api/servicios, que sea SaaS con lo cual te hara pensar de enviar siempre por ejempo el cliente  "Conectado" para conocer el template o que modulos tiene habilitado. Aqui es un solo App que se "personalizada" por el cliente "logeado" (y la vendes como Serviio o la instalas individualmente). Lo bueno de esto muy fácil de aplicar cambios para todos)
2. OPCION 2: Tener varios proyectos separado por cliente (incluso podrías tener template en VS ya pre armado) e ir insertando (lo malo de esto ultimo es para cambios que sea del CORE es mas difícil de implementarlos en todos)

Bueno... las recomendaciones

**RECOMENDACIÓN 1: Modalizar comportamiento (plugins) con MEF**

Si te tendria que recomendar algo seria.. [MEF -Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd460648.aspx) la idea es simple "poder inyectar modulos/plugins con solo copiar o subir un assemblie" (incluso podrias tener un servidor de modulos para ir agregando a tu "proyecto core" 
Asi podras [utilizar MEF en MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh708870.aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5001478)

**RECOMENDACION 2:Paquetes separados (modulos) en NuGet interno**

Algunos componentes los podrias hacer "modulares" y desacoplarlos completamente de tu Core. PAra que sean Testeables por sobre todo y reusables.. .para ello lo puedes crear en proyectos *separados y solos* y luego compartilos a nivel empresarial en tu propio repositorio de paquetes ([un NuGet interno](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)).

Bueno son ideas y recomendaciones,

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar o guiar

- [MEF -Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd460648.aspx)
- [MEF -Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerAddingMEFAndPluginsToASPNETMVC.aspx)
- [Injecting MVC with MEF 2 in 2 Minutes](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Injecting-MVC-with-MEF-2-in-2-Minutes?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5001478)
- [ASP.NET MVC Extensibility with MEF](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/03/14/asp-dotnet-extensibility-with-mef.aspx)
- [Como utilizar MEF en MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh708870.aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5001478)
- [Using MEF with MVC by defining a ControllerFactory](http://christianjvella.com/wordpress/mef-mvc-defining-controllerfactory/)
- [ASP.NET MVC and the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-(MEF).aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Este parece un problema común de dependencia, lo que quieres hacer es "bueno", ya que quieres hacer core que tenga toda la lógica principal, de un producto, que parece que se les venderá a varios clientes como propio, pero cada uno tendrá cosas únicas.

Esto haría que quedaras con una arquitectura parecida a esta

[image: Arquitectura de soluciones]

Donde en principal está toda la lógica común esta en PRINCIPAL, y cada cliente tiene un pequeño fragmento de lógica que es diferente de todos los demás.

Avanzado el proyecto, cada cliente te pedirá cosas que solo son para él y tendrías algo así

[image: Arquitectura de soluciones]

Pero debes de tener en cuenta que PRINCIPAL no se va a modificar nunca por el requerimiento de un cliente, cuando todos necesiten algo, sería mejor agregarlo en principal y mandarlo llamar.

Con lo anterior

> Toda la lógica, incluida la de las soluciones N se encuentra en la
>   Solución principal, lo cual la idea es que las soluciones N hagan
>   Referencia a las DLL de la solución principal. Es correcto esto?

- Si es aceptable, pero no quiere decir que sea fácil, y es mucho mejor que tener N Soluciones con `copy/paste` de funcionalidad que serán casi imposible de mantener

> El problema que le encuentro a esto es que si un cliente necesita un requerimiento especifico que debería hacer?

- Agregarlo en su propia lógica, con una condición, por ejemplo, *una nueva consulta para extraer las ventas del año separada por quincenas* ninguno de los otros clientes la ha solicitado, pero pudiera ser que en un futuro la necesiten, ¿que prosigue? agregar funcionalidad en PRINCIPAL y solo referenciarla en la lógica del cliente.
- Por el contrario si un cliente pide cambiar el *requerimiento x80* que dice que la `consultaEjemplo` regresa `A`, que para todos los clientes es igual y esta se encuentra en PRINCIPAL, pero él desea que ahora regrese `AB`, se debe sobrescribir en la lógica del cliente, sin afectar PRINCIPAL.

---

Ahora, sobre el tema de cómo organizar las soluciones en visual studio, creo que es un poco más subjetivo, ya que se debería usar la que a cada persona le agrede más, por ejemplo:

> Puedes tener una super solución, con tus 1000 DLL's que tienen toda la
>   Lógica principal, y cada proyecto mvc y web api de cada cliente, quizá
>   con sus respectivas DLL

Ventajas:

- Todo está en un solo lugar

Desventajas:

- La carga del proyecto va a ser más lenta (La laptop del becario de 1 GB de RAM, no va a cargar la solución XD )
- El control de código (Dígase [git](/questions/tagged/git), [tfs](/questions/tagged/tfs), etc) podría no ser el más adecuado, cuando alguien haga un commit, podrían referenciarse cosas sin sentido, haciendo un poco difícil el *track* de los commits
- Todos los programadores tienen acceso al código principal, y pueden dañarlo o robarlo

> Puedes tener una solución para el core y una solución con todos los
>   proyectos mvc y web api.

Ventajas:

- La carga de las soluciones es mejor que en la opción 1
- Un programador que no tenga que modificar el principal, solo usara la solución de clientes, y no estará en riesgo el código principal

Desventajas:

- Se requiere configurar dos repositorios para el control de código fuente, en lugar de solo uno

> Puedes tener una solución para el core y tener tantas soluciones como
>   clientes tengas, con sus proyectos mvc y web api y quizá DLL's.

Ventajas:

- Un programador que no tenga que ver el código del cliente A, porque solo trabaja para el cliente B, no podrá hacerlo ya que solo necesita la solución de B
- La carga de la solución es la más rápida

Desventajas:

- Necesitas muchos repositorios o en su defecto sub-repositorios, o alguna otra estrategia de control de código fuente, de cualquier forma esta opción es la más difícil de configurar.

Así que como ves, depende mucho de cómo te organizas, de los métodos de seguridad que quieras tener, o la facilidad de configuración de ambientes, lo más probable es que se me haya ido algún otra ventaja o desventaja, pero seguro algún compañero de SO en español, nos ayudara.

Answer (score 2):

Siempre encontrarás mil formas diferentes de abordar este problema, te comparto el resultado de mis vivencias personales algunas en concordancia con otras alternativas expuestas y otras en total desacuerdo.

En los proyectos grandes corporativos, sobre todo en los **multiempresa** siempre encontrarás este escenario.

Lo habitual es que los clientes demanden personalizaciones de acuerdo a sus necesidades y es aquí donde las decisiones de arquitectura física, lógica y de procesos es de vital importancia.

Mi solución recomendada aparece más abajo como

#### Aplicación multitenant, y el mundo del software como servicio**

Por ahora acá dejo mis notas.

### Múltiples proyectos o soluciones, 1 por cada cliente.

Es la peor solución posible, entre más proyectos tenga la solución mucho más lento será el proceso de cargue y compilación. Esta alternativa parece ser buena pero realmente está creando muchos problemas colaterales especialmente de **redundancia de código**. Con el tiempo será inevitable que esto suceda y no habrá metodología ni proceso que lo evite.

Puedes intentar manteniendo unos proyectos core que sean 'intocables' y solo tener unos cuantos personalizables para cada cliente, pero conforme la solución crezca verás como por necesidades muy puntuales de un cliente específico comienzas a tener fugas de código del core para migrarlas a cada cliente.

### Souciones por medio de patrones de diseño e inyección de dependencias

Esta aproximación es un poco mejor, una buena arquitectura e implementación de patrones de  diseño pueden desacoplar bastante tu código para llegar a tener una solución altamente personalizable donde por medio de configuración puedas establecer la resolución de instancias de objetos que posean la lógica determinada por cada cliente.

No necesitarás abrir múltiples proyectos sino más bien crear clases personalizadas según la necesidad de cada cliente, y luego en el proceso de instalación para cada uno de ellos modificar la configuración de la aplicación para que cada cliente utilice los objetos que sean pertinentes.

El lío de esta metodología es que tu aplicación tiende a ser más grande y desordenada conforme pasa el tiempo. Cada cliente nuevo puede requerir un sin fin de configuraciones para inyección de dependencias y a la final pese al alto valor técnico que tenga tu aplicación el nivel de entropía y esfuerzo en mantenimiento será alto, esta última parte en especial es el escenario típico de una aplicación con un alto valor técnico pero una gran complejidad en el código lo cual dificultará el mantenimiento de la aplicación durante su ciclo de vida.

### Versionamiento por cliente

Puedes crear un branch nuevo de la aplicación por cada cliente, en este caso tendrías una sola solución y conjunto de proyectos, pero cada que debas hacer un cambio fuera de lo estandard creas un nuevo branch de la aplicación.

Esto te dará flexibilidad de aplicar cambios o nuevas características solo a un cliente determinado sin crear un conjunto de soluciones o proyectos diferentes (aunque a la larga lo serán).

De esta forma debes mantener un branch ppal o core, con  la aplicación en su versión estándar y asegurarte que cada cambio sea replicado a todos los branch y personalizado luego en cada branch según sea necesario.

En todo caso aunque te libras de los proyectos con gran complejidad por el uso exagerado de patrones y de inyección de dependencias, y de los problemas de compilador al tener soluciones con múltiples proyectos, a la final tendrás un tema bastante complejo de administrar con el tema de versiones abriendo paso a muchos errores y diferencias 'extrañas' entre un branch y otro.

Pese a eso es una de las soluciones más ampliamente adoptadas por las casas de software.

### Los plugin / MEF

Es una excelente alternativa, que ademas da mucha flexibilidad en medio de un  marco ampliamente probado.

Sin embargo no lo recomendaría tanto para LOBs, si bien funciona. Porque dada la cantidad de cambios posibles la complejidad de la aplicación se desbordara y la cantidad de plugins te podría traer algunas complicaciones de performance. Nada más echa una mirada a cómo se comporta Visual Studio cuando tienes muchos plug-ins o extensiones instalados

### Aplicación multitenant, y el mundo del software como servicio

Para los tiempos modernos esta es mi mejor opción y de lejos!
Si tu aplicación es multicliente de plano deberías pensar el porque tienes que instalar tu aplicación en cada cliente si probablemente tú puedas ofrecerla como un servicio en la nube, llegando a más clientes y con unos costos de implementación y mantenimiento considerablemente mejores.

El punto es que aún sino quieres/puedes/sabes vender tu aplicación como servicio en la nube, esta misma arquitectura multitenant te brindará enormes beneficios al momento de construir y mantener tu base de código.

Lo que debes hacer es construir la aplicación como si en efecto sobre una misma instancia múltiples clientes se conectaran.

Esto implica que tu aplicación debe comportarse de maneras diferentes por cada cliente , pero dado que conoce desde el comienzo esa situación, dicha personalización es lograda por parámetros de configuración interpretados desde el código, no preguntando porqué cliente está conectado sino por que características de configuración están establecidas para este cliente específico.

Entonces en tu código tendrías algo como esto

```
//Cargar configuración del cliente, en una LOB grande
//estos suelen ser parametros en una tabla de la BD
//usualmente solo se hace el cargue cuando el usuario 
//inicia sesión
var ConfiguraciónCliente = CargarConfiguraciónCliente();

If(ConfiguraciónCliente.PagaImpuestoIVA)
{
   FacturarIVA ConfiguraciónCliente.PorcentajeIVA);
}
elseif (ConfiguraciónCliente.ObligadoaDeclararRenta)
{
  DeclararRenta():
}
```