# Multiples proyectos mvc en la misma solucion c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

quería consultar que me recomiendan. Tengo un proyecto grande con muchos clientes y requerimientos diferentes para ciertas cosas. Mi idea es tener un proyecto MVC genérico con los controllers, vistas y scripts que se repiten en todos los clientes y un proyecto MVC extra para cada cliente con los controllers, vistas y scripts específicos de cada cliente. Además de esto tengo un proyecto Web Api, en el cual se encuentran todos los Web Services. No me sirven las áreas ya que a la hora de publicarle el sitio a cada cliente no quiero que tengas cosas de otros clientes. Y además necesito tener los proyectos separados por organización. El problema es que la ejecución no pasa por los startup de los diferentes proyectos MVC, pasa solo por uno y por el startup de la WebApi.

**En resumen, se pueden correr dos aplicaciones MVC al mismo tiempo y que interactuen entre si, osea que yo pueda consumir un controller de la aplicaciòn MVC B desde la aplicacion MVC A, como se hace para configurar las url??
Que es lo que se puede hacer para solucionar este problema, que me recomiendan. Muchas gracias.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**En la imagen se puede ver la estructura de la solución, la idea es correr GenericWebProject + WebApi + Uno de los otros Proyectos MVC.**

Comment: Hola alejandro y bienvenido. Para que la pregunta sea válida debes compartir el código que mencionas siendo este lo más reducido posible. Un saludo!

Comment: Es que no es algo basicamente de codigo, sino mas de estructura de la aplicación, y de si es posible tener dos aplicaciones MVC en la misma solución y correrlas al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Creo que esto te puede ayudar http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3176/2027

Comment: Gracias, ya lo habia leido a ese post, como digo en el post, la principal duda es como levantar dos aplicaciones mvc en una misma soluciòn.

Comment: crea un un custom cotrollerfactory y en el haces el load de los controllers que necesites (ej. dll con controllers cliente, otra con ventas o dll con controllers compartidos )

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas hacer es tener corriendo en paralelo varios proyectos a la vez tenes que hacer click derecho sobre el proyecto y en el menu contextual buscar 'Debug' y luego 'Start new instance'.

[image: Captura Debug nueva instancia]

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería tener diferentes soluciones que carguen los proyectos específicos, en las que se repiten los proyectos obviamente apuntás simpre a los mismos proyecto, no sé si encaja con tu requerimiento.